# HTML changing of button function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have this code below that hide and shows the table cells by clicking the button. But the problem is i only want `button1` to be able to use the function and not both, does anyone have any suggestion on how to do it? I tried to change the button class id and all but its still not working. Any suggestion would be appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>

<table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Maniac</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>


<button>button1</button>
<button>button2</button>

<script>
$('table').find('tr:gt(2)').hide();
$("button").on("click", function() {
$('table').find('tr:gt(2)').toggle();
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding a class or an ID to the button and in the selector use that class/ ID as afilter.
For example ```<button id="toggle-td">button1</button>```
and in jquery use ```$("button#toggle-td")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add some class/id to button1 and bind click event to that selector.

```js
$('table').find('tr:gt(2)').hide();
$(".button1").on("click", function() {
  $('table').find('tr:gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Maniac</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hello</td></tr>   
</table>


<button class="button1">button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with your button:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Maniac</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hello</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <button class="button1">button1</button>
    <button class="button2">button2</button>

    <script>
        $('table').find('tr:gt(2)').hide();
        $(".button1").on("click", function () {
            $('table').find('tr:gt(2)').toggle();
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its simple. Add id to the button you want to perform the action on, and then use that id to have a click event on it. Here is the example : Add id="button1" in button tag in your html.

```
<button id="button1">button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```

and then your script should be :

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(2)').hide();
$("#button1").on("click", function() {
  $('table').find('tr:gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

Using this, you'll be able to have your action on only button 1 and not both.

You can also use the class instead of id. Here is how it goes :

```
<button class="button1">button1</button>
<button>button2</button>
```

and then your script should be :

```
$('table').find('tr:gt(2)').hide();
$(".button1").on("click", function() {
  $('table').find('tr:gt(2)').toggle();
});
```

> Conclusion : Adding Class or id to an html tag, makes it unique to
>   perform a different function on.

Do this and here you go. Happy Coding !